# How to convert UTC time to EST time in App Engine Java

Tags: google-app-engine, timezone, google-cloud-datastore

I realized that GAE datastore automatically converts the time to UTC time. It is somehow converted back when displaying on client side.  However, when I get the time on server side, it is still using the UTC time.

I know in python we can use this utility http://timezones.appspot.com/  but my application was written in Java and it uses Objectify to communicate with appengine datastore.

Is there any Java classes that convert the UTC time back to EST time on the server side?

Comment: Couldn't you use java.util.Calendar.getInstance( TimeZone.getTimeZone( "EST" ))?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use JodaTime (http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) which is the default answer for most Java data questions.